# How to see these two sigma algebras are the same?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

$X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^p$ be a random vector measurable with respect to $\mathcal{R}^p$,the Borel $\sigma$ -field in $\mathbb{R}^p$. Suppose a matrix $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times r}$, where $r \leq p$.In the textbook, there is a sentence:

> ...the $\sigma$ -fields $(X, \beta^T X)$ and $\sigma(X)$ are identical...

Why the above is true?

Comment: Because $f(X)$ gives you no more information if you already have $X$

Comment: @Andrew Emm. So sigma-algebra means information? I thought it's some good collection of sets.

Comment: one often thinks of sigma-algebras as meaning information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sigma(X)$ is the collection of all events $X^{-1}(B)$ where $B \in \mathcal{R}^p$ is a Borel set.

Now if $C \in \mathcal{R}^r$, then $(\beta^T X)^{-1}(C) = X^{-1}((\beta^T)^{-1}(C))$.  But $\beta^T$, being a linear map, is in particular continuous and thus Borel, so $(\beta^T)^{-1}(C) \in \mathcal{R}^p$.  Hence $(\beta^T X)^{-1}(C)$ is of the form $X^{-1}(B)$ for some $B \in \mathcal{R}^p$, and so it is already in $\sigma(X)$.